# Display only Alt text in image tag html

Tags: jquery, html, src

I want to display only alt text if the image is not there in the path. It is displaying properly in Firefox, but in chrome it displays broken image link then alt text. I tried doing like this

I tried jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function hideImage(img)
{
   img.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't even display alt text. How to display alt text through this.

Answer (score 5):

**CSS Solution** - May not be compatible in older browsers

---

Using the **[attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#wikiArticle)** expression. You can replace the default alt text that shows, by positioning the pseudo-element on top of the default text, hiding it from view.

```css
img:after {  
  content: attr(alt);
  font-size: 16px;      
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<img src="doesnt_exist.jpg" alt="No Image" />
```

Credits to **[Styling Broken Images](https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/)** there are more cool tricks there.

Comment: Very nice to see a pure-CSS solution for this one!

Comment: Really nice solution, but be aware it won't work in legacy browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is true.. Since you already gave a jquery solution I thought Ill add this one too.. Anyways thanks for the heads up I mentioned  the same in the answer

Comment: Trust me, I'd love a world where we could use this. Damn IE holding us all back. Upvoted this for you :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks brother :) .. I wish IE would evolve into a better browser over night..

Answer (score 4):

You can hook to the `error` event that gets raised when an `img` element fails to load. You can then call `replaceWith()` to show the `alt` text in its place. Try this:

```js
$('img').on('error', function() {
  $(this).replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).prop('alt');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here's an image that won't load: <img src="doesnt_exist.jpg" alt="foo bar" />
```

Comment: But it doesn't work in Chrome, it shows both , broken image and al text.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome - that's what I'm using right now. Check the console for errors with your code.